# MYSQL query, loop all rows, based on specific field value run loop with another query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as the follows:

Purchases:

| Purchase_id | Stations |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |

And another table:

allItems:

| Item_id | Purchase_id | Product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

Im doing a query to get all purchases with no NULL value under Stations:

`SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE Stations IS NOT NULL`

Let's say I got the Purchases table above and I want to start go through it and insert into the allItems table a row for each station.
For example the first row I got has a Stations value of 4, I want to insert into the aallItems table the following row 4 times, the second row where Stations value is 6, i'd like to insert the following 6 times.

`INSERT INTO allItems(Purchase_id, Products_id) VALUES (??Not sure what to insert here i need the Purchase_id from the row??, 17)`

expected outcome should be the added last 4 rows:

allItems:

| Item_id | Purchase_id | Product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 17 |
| 2 | 1 | 17 |
| 3 | 1 | 17 |
| 4 | 1 | 17 |
| 5 | 2 | 17 |
| 6 | 2 | 17 |
| 7 | 2 | 17 |
| 8 | 2 | 17 |
| 9 | 2 | 17 |
| 10 | 2 | 17 |

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I am not clear if you should end up with 5 rows in allitems (the existing row + 4 duplicates) or 4 rows. Please add expected outcome visually.

Comment: i've edited and added the expected outcome, thanx for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write a stored procedure for that like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FILLSP()
        BEGIN
        DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE count INT;
        DECLARE repeat INT;
        DECLARE pid INT;
        DECLARE i INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Purchases INTO count;
        
        WHILE counter < count  DO 
          SELECT Stations FROM Purchases LIMIT counter,1 INTO repeat;
          SELECT Purchase_id FROM Purchases LIMIT counter,1 INTO pid;
          SET i = 0;
          WHILE i < repeat DO
          INSERT INTO allItems VALUES (pid, 17);
          SET i = i + 1;
          END WHILE;
          SET counter = counter + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END
```